# Error enabling AD authentication in GPFS filesystem

Tags: filesystems

Ive created a filesystem on a 2 linux node(both running RHEL 7) GPFS cluster.  I am trying to enable AD authentication but am receiving an error and unable to find an answer to fix.  Here is the process I am following on the manager node:

```
./spectrumscale file auth ad
```

Yes to edit template

I fill in the template with the following info:

```
[file_ad]
servers = bdtestdc01 <--- my test AD server
netbios_name = gpfscluser <--- the name I gave the cluster during setup Is  this field looking for another name?
idmap_role = master
bind_username = administrator
bind_password = the domain password of the administrator account

unixmap_domains = bdtest.subdomain.company.com
```

I save the template and set the password.  I then run:

```
./spectrumscale deploy
```

It errors at Installing Authentication.  The log file says:

```
Error executing action run on resource 'execute[Configure file authentication]

2015-12-21 10:45:31,440 [ TRACE ] bdgpfs01.subdomain.company.com Chef Client failed. 1 resources updated in 3.641691552 seconds
2015-12-21 10:45:31,456 [ TRACE ] bdgpfs01.subdomain.company.com [2015-12-21T10:45:31-08:00] ERROR: execute[Configure file authentication] (auth::auth_file_configure line 22) had an error: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: Expected process to exit with [0], but received '1'
2015-12-21 10:45:31,456 [ TRACE ] bdgpfs01.subdomain.company.com ---- Begin output of /usr/lpp/mmfs/bin/mmuserauth service create --data-access-method file --type ad --servers 'bdtestbluedc01' --netbios-name 'gpfscluster' --idmap-role 'master' --user-name 'administrator' --password XXXXXX --unixmap-domains 'bdtest.subdomain.company.com' --idmap-range '10000000-299999999' --idmap-range-size '1000000' --enable-nfs-kerberos ----
2015-12-21 10:45:31,456 [ TRACE ] bdgpfs01.subdomain.company.com STDOUT:
2015-12-21 10:45:31,457 [ TRACE ] bdgpfs01.subdomain.company.com STDERR: mmuserauth service create: Syntax error. The correct syntax is:
2015-12-21 10:45:31,457 [ TRACE ] bdgpfs01.subdomain.company.com   --unixmap-domains domain(lower value-higher value)
2015-12-21 10:45:31,457 [ TRACE ] bdgpfs01.subdomain.company.com mmuserauth service create: Command failed. Examine previous error messages to determine cause.
2015-12-21 10:45:31,438 [ TRACE ] bdgpfs01.subdomain.company.com     mmuserauth service create: Command failed. Examine previous error messages to determine cause.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The domain field was looking for nonwhitespace characters and an ID Map Range.

Instead of using the configuration template, I ran the following command which enabled the authentication successfully...

```
mmuserauth service create --type ad --data-access-method file --netbios-name bdtestnode --user-name administrator --idmap-role master --servers myADserver --password Passwr0rd --idmap-range-size 1000000 --idmap-range 10000000-299999999
```

I then ran the following command to test:

```
id "testdomain\administrator"
```

It returned the proper groups and IDs